# How to split one column into multiple columns with pipes acting as a separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strsplit

I'm trying to split the content below into multiple columns, separated by | or multiple pipes. For example, what you see below should have split into 8 columns.

> By the end of the week, you will have the opportunity to: | | Explain
> the accrual basis of accounting and the reasons for adjusting entries.
> | Prepare adjusting entries for deferrals. | Prepare adjusting entries
> for accruals. | Prepare an adjusted trial balance and closing entries.
> | | |

I used the following code:

```
df2 = df1['los'].str.split('|', expand=True)
```

I noticed that some rows didn't get split into different columns using the code above. Any ideas why?

Comment: It will be 9 columns not 8. Also what are those rows that didn't split into 9 columns?

Comment: Sorry, yes 9 columns. I used final.head() to check the outcome and that was where I saw that .split() didn't work for some rows.  

https://github.com/hellokatechan/clean_los/blob/main/clean_los_manual%20.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression pattern:

```
df['col'].str.split('( ?\| ?)+')
```